# Interpreting JavaScript outside of the browser?

Tags: .net, javascript, clr

This is more out of curiosity that a real requirement, but I'm wondering if it's possible to treat JavaScript as (ideally) a first-class .NET citizen, or (secondarily) have some way of invoking/interpreting pure JavaScript functions (that don't require the DOM) in a desktop setting?

Has anyone ever attempted implementing a CLR version of JavaScript? Something tugs at the back of my mind concerning this, but now that I think about it it was probably PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your second option, there's [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine)) and [things like it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages).

Answer (score 4):

Using the DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime) you can use Managed JScript.  See the official JScript blog from Microsoft here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2007/05/04/managed-jscript-announced.aspx

This is goes for Ruby (IronRuby), Python (IronPython), and Dynamic VB.  You can also write your own DLR language.

Answer (score 2):

[JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bf5fs13.aspx) is available on .NET as a first-class citizen. It's not exactly JavaScript, but it may be close enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page, there used to be 2 "implementations" on the CLR:

http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/nettools/articles/8060.aspx

But both seem to be dead...

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible to run JavaScript applications without the use of a web browser. You can do this just by running the application using cscript (typically javascript files end with .js).

Comment: Oh hey Pete! Didn't notice that was you. :) Unfortunately I'm looking for a solution that I can embed into an application, but that's interesting and I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Going well--I've given up on WPF and am switching to the web side of things a la ASP.NET MVC, AJAX and such nifty acronyms. ;) Luckily my work is not bound to any particular OS (though my knowledge is still mostly .NET).

Answer (score 0):

You can also run .js files with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Hope this helps someone else.